# How to access the last expression used in search in Vim?

Tags: vim

When doing more complicated `search & replace` operation in Vim I often try it out in `search` and only if it finds what I expect I use `search & replace`.

Is there a way how to access the last value from `search` and put it into `search & replace` or alternatively, to put this last value into a `register`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [VIM wiki page](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace):

```
:%s//<c-r>//g
    Replace each match of the last search pattern with the / register (the last search pattern). 
    After pressing Ctrl-R then / to insert the last search pattern (and before pressing Enter to perform the command), you could edit the text to make any required change.
```

Comment: Good. I did not know that `/` is register as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to edit the search regex you can omit it and vim will use the last search for the pattern.

```
:%s//<replacement>/
```

---

From `:h :s | /If the {pattern}`

```
If the {pattern} for the substitute command is empty, the command uses the
pattern from the last substitute or `:global` command.  If there is none, but
there is a previous search pattern, that one is used.  With the [r] flag, the
command uses the pattern from the last substitute, `:global`, or search
command.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can edit your search history by pressing <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>.

Your search history will open in a separate file, spit vertically.

You can navigate and edit each line like a normal Vim session.

To execute a search, hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on any line.

To cancel, hit <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> to close the search history window.

You can copy and paste things to and from this window.

You can also edit your *command* history by pressing <kbd>q</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>.